# unable to set background color of div with absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie to html/css and am trying to create my first webpage.
I am unable to set background colour for div with class `inner`. As of now this div is displaying background colour set in `banner-bottom` class.

Following is my html:

```css
    .banner-bottom{
      background:#F7F7F7;
      padding:1em 1em;
      text-align:center;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .floatleft {
     float:left;
     width: 25%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    .floatright {
     float:right;
     width: 75%;
     background-color: #EEE;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .inner{
     position: absolute;
     height:100%;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #1b1b1b;
     width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="banner-bottom" width="100%" > 
         <div class="floatleft"><input  type="button" class="pink_btn" value="Who?"/></div>
         <div class="floatright"><div class="inner"> some values here</div></div>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

Any pointers on what I may be doing wrong?
Thanks help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem pops up when you set the `height: 100%` to your `inner` class. Absolute positioned elements are treated different because they break the box model of the DOM. You might want to use `top` `bottom` `left` and `right` properties to place the absolute positioned element where you want.

HTML:

```css
.banner-bottom{
  background:#F7F7F7;
  padding:1em 1em;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}

.floatleft {
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}

.floatright {
    float:right;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #EEE;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner{
    color: white; /* added to see the text in the black background */
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    right: 175px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-bottom" width="100%" > 
     <div class="floatleft"><input  type="button" class="pink_btn" value="Who?"/></div>
     <div class="floatright"><div class="inner"> some values here</div></div>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I added `color: white;` to `.inner` to see the text in the black background, you can change it depending on your preference.

Comment: Thanks for solving this problem. But now I am faced with another issue: I want the height to be 100% so that both left and right floating `div` are of equal height. Which is why I added the extra `div` and `inner` class with `absolute` positioning in the first place. I also need to control background colour of right div to show separation of the left and right divs. Should I post this as a new separate question?

Comment: If you want you can post another question, but I can help you with that in this thread, don't worry. Give me some time I am in lunch time. I will take a look at it later :)

Comment: ... but adding a z-index to the absolutely positioned element might help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the defined height in `.inner`, because absolute positioning is not equal as relative. If you define 100% height in this case will be zero height. Change it to a PX or EM value or directly remove it. And take care with absolute and fixed positioning, sure will be lots of another solutions less dangerous

```css
    .banner-bottom{
      background:#ff0000;
      padding:1em 1em;
      text-align:center;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .floatleft {
     float:left;
     width: 25%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    .floatright {
     float:right;
     width: 75%;
     background-color: #EEE;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .inner{
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
        color: white;
     background-color: #1b1b1b;
     width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="banner-bottom" width="100%" > 
         <div class="floatleft"><input  type="button" class="pink_btn" value="Who?"/></div>
         <div class="floatright"><div class="inner"> some values here</div></div>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```